# Change the color of a global action that references a VF page (from being the default purple) in S1 mobile?

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, global-actions

Is this possible to do declaritively change this action color to match the 'visualforce tab' color just like how custom object tab colors carry over?

Trying to make this purple action match the VF tab color...

[image]
[image: ...these tab color settings]

Answer (score 0):

I have been wondering this for months now. I will ping someone at SFDC who might be able to help answer this, or find the answer!